# Can we HTTP 2 server push assets present in other CDN?

Tags: angular, tomcat, cdn, http2

Currently the index.html file of my angular app is generated from a tomcat server(Apache Coyete). The index.html file consists js, css and images pointing to our own CDN. Example:

`<script src="https://mc1.mcdn.in/main.adjhf432hjh23k44.js" />`

Suppose I want to server push 'https://mc1.mcdn.in/main.adjhf432hjh23k44.js' file. Is it possible to server push a CDN link? Also, Is there any way to server push all the files that match a pattern? like main.{hash}.js polyfills.{hash}.js etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only push items from a connection which is authorative for the domain of the resource. [From the HTTP/2 specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-8.2):

> A client MUST treat a PUSH_PROMISE for which the server is not authoritative as a stream error... of type PROTOCOL_ERROR

So if the index file is also served via the CDN, then you can push the static assets on that connection. But if the index.html is served from a separate domain and IP address to the assets then they cannot be pushed.

You can use the [preload resource hint](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/resource-prioritization) to prioritise items (particularly late discovered resources) which many advise as four enough, given HTTP/2 push’s [complexities and browser support](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/h2-push-tougher-than-i-thought/).

Comment: Thanks Barry. So suppose I serve the index.html file from the CDN, is there any way I could use regex on the web server for assets to be pushed. E.g main.js file contains hash (main.hd557337rhghd78.js) and this hash will change on every build. So is there a way I could use pattern on web server to identify resource to be pushed?

Comment: Not really, but it depends on how your CDN pushes and how your index.html is generated. Some CDNs push based on `preload` link headers and if the index.html is dynamically generated, and it must know the exact URL and has to use, so you could just return `preload` headers with the exact URL to enable the push. If index.html is statically generated and/or the CDN pushes based on some other method then this gets harder.